# Can a radio on VOX detect a loud tone and interpret as a cut on transmission (coming from pilot/cockpit)?

Tags: general-aviation, radio-communications

Can a radio using VOX detect a short tone and interpret it as a signal for cutoff of audio signal/transmission? this is A/G radio communication using a Schmid radio

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why this couldn't be done, but I am not aware of any system implementing such a technology. One potential problem is that something else in the cockpit could make such a sound and cut the transmission; alternatively, background noise could drown out the tone. Perhaps a better option would be to simply have a button to stop the transmission; some kind of device to generate the tone would be needed anyway, so it makes more sense to have whatever input would have gone to the tone generator go directly to the radio.

Comment: An update regarding the topic. This question originated from a coupling issue. Two frequencies are coupled, and the retransmission frequency was found to be the source of the tone.

Comment: @CommSys_noob01 oh, sorry; I misunderstood your question. I thought you were asking if having a tone cut the transmission could be implemented on purpose as a feature. Did you get your problem fixed?

Comment: Nope, not really. there's still this tone present but it's thought to be the PTT of the other radio(the retransmission freq) which is coupled.

Comment: @CommSys_noob01 you need to edit that info into your original question, not bury it down here in the comments on an answer.